# Parsing c string to int in objective-c avoiding overflow

Tags: c++, objective-c, c, parsing, int

In objective-c would I parse a c string (not `NSStirng`) to an int whilst also checking if the number is not too big or too small for an int?

I've found some useful references like this: http://www.fefe.de/intof.html

But I've not been able to find an example piece of code that will show me how to do this. I've tried playing with `strtoumax()` and `UINT_MAX` but have not found enough clear examples in order to know how to use them correctly.

I also know to avoid `atoi()`

### Update 2014.04.12

Is something like this wise? I think it's dodgy how I'm using a `long` and then change it back into an `int`. The other thing is that I've completely removed `&& errno == ERANGE` as it was just not working with it. Is this also wise?

```
bool to_int(const char* str, int* val) 
{     
    char* nptr = NULL;
    long x = strtol(str, &nptr, 10);  
    printf("long %ld\n",x);
    if (((x > INT_MAX) || (x < INT_MIN))) 
        return false; //Value is invalid..  

    *val = (int)x;
    return true; // Value is valid
}


int main()
{

    int val = 0;
    char testVal[] = "2147483647";
    
    if (to_int(testVal, &val))
    {
        printf("Valid integer: %d\n", val);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Invalid integer %d\n", val);
    }     
}
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

bool to_int(const char* str, int* val) //Takes a string and a pointer to an int.
{
    errno = 0;
    *val = 0;
    char* nptr = NULL;
    long int lval = strtol(str, &nptr, 10);

    if (((lval > INT_MAX) || (lval < INT_MIN) || (lval == LONG_MAX) || (lval == LONG_MIN)) && errno == ERANGE) //Check for ERANGE being set.
        return false; //Value is invalid..

    errno = 0;
    *val = (int)lval;
    return true; //Value is valid..
}


int main()
{
    int val = 0;

    if (to_int("2147483647", &val))
    {
        printf("Valid integer: %d", val);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Invalid integer");
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to set `errno = 0` before calling `strtol()` because a *successful*  conversion does not reset the errno.

Comment: Note `strtol` returns a `long`, not an `int`. You probably shouldn't assume the types are equivalent, as on certain platforms, `int` is 32-bits, and `long` is 64 bits, which will make your error checking code incorrect.

Comment: You're right @RichardJ.RossIII I require a conversion specifically to int not to long. Is there another way around this for ints? Maybe using INT_MAX/INT_MIN?

Comment: Ahh totally forgot. The reason was because I was using: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol  as a guide.. and `std::stoi` uses it directly.. I forgot to check for `INT_MAX` and `INT_MIN`. Anyway, I've fixed it. It should be much safer now. The first set of or statements might not even need the `LONG_MIN` and `LONG_MAX` comparisons then.. It's short circuited as well so I doubt it'd get there. I used the `strtol` because `strtoimax` didn't set `errno` like its docs said.. :l

Comment: @CantChooseUsernames using your updated code I need to remove the "&& errno == ERANGE" clause to have it detect the valid integers correctly. If I set the test string to "2147483648" it will tell me that -2147483648 is a valid integer, removing the ERANGE check fixes this. If I printf ERANGE I get a value of 34. I'm not sure what's going on there. I'm on XCode 5.1

Comment: That's the exact same problem I had with the `strtoimax`. errno is supposed to be set to ERANGE. On gcc (windows), it works: https://ideone.com/0XuNqH I'm actually not sure why either. Might be a bug. I didn't get to test it on XCode yet but I assumed if it works in C, it'll work in Objective-C (I haven't had any problems with this assumption so far).

Comment: Weird, well I'll make it off as answer accepted but also leave my solution there so if anyone gets stuck with yours the can try mine. Thank you!